# Linux ip command option s

Tags: linux, ip, command

I saw below command from a shell script.
It's ip command in linux but I cannot find the meaning of the option `-s`.

```
ryan@mylaptop:~$ ip -s li ls dev wlp0s20f3
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:79:6e:da:bb:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped missed  mcast   
    80207830   156564   0       3       0       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    17803267   97628    0       0       0       0
```

I can see `-s` means "stats" in the man page. But what is `li` stats?
And what other state can I choose?
I can assume `ls dev wlp0s20f3` is "list device wlp0s20f3", not sure about `-s`.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `I can see -s means "state"` ... look again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you misread then man page. The `-s` stands for `stats` or `statistics`, not for state. And statistics is what you got from this command.
In addition, the ip command is more complex than it first appears. See the **SEE ALSO** section at the bottom of the man page for more **ip** commands. Including `ip-link`. And that's also what `li` means – **link**. The only dot in the command that is misleading is `ls`. This is not listed in the man page, but has the effect of "show". If you look at the `ip-link` man page, you'll find a lot more options than in the `ip` man page. I hope that clarifies things a bit.